# Row to column transform in snowflake and get a single row

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to transform rows into columns.

Input :

| Elementid | Element | Scale | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oral | Importance | 4.5 |
| 1 | Oral | Level | 4.8 |
| 1 | Text | Importance | 4.0 |
| 1 | Text | Level | 4.2 |

Output Required:

| Elementid | Element | Importance | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oral | 4.5 | 4.8 |
| 1 | Text | 4.0 | 4.2 |

I am using `PIVOT` for this :

```
 select Elementid,
 Element,
 "'Importance'" as Importance,
 "'Level'" as Level,
 Date
 from  Input Table
 pivot(sum(Value) for Scale in ('Importance', 'Level') ) as p;
```

| Elementid | Element | Importance | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Oral | 4.5 | Null |
| 1 | Oral | Null | 4.8 |
| 1 | Text | 4.0 | Null |
| 1 | Text | Null | 4.2 |

How to get single row for the Element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assumption*: Your example data doesn't include values for `Date`.
I'm assuming they are different for the same element for at least some of the input rows, which is why you're getting multiple rows.

In order to get a single row for each element, you could group by `Elementid` and `Element` and use the sum (or min/max) over `Importance` and `Level`:

```sql
with pivoted as (
select Elementid,
Element,
"'Importance'" as Importance,
"'Level'" as Level,
Date
from  input
pivot(sum(Value) for Scale in ('Importance', 'Level') ) as p
)
select Elementid, Element,
SUM(Importance) as Importance, -- use your aggregation of choice
SUM(Level) as Level 
from pivoted
group by Elementid, Element; -- assuming you want to ignore the Date
```

Or, if you prefer inline views:

```sql
select Elementid, Element, SUM(Importance) as Importance, SUM(Level) as Level 
from (
select Elementid,
Element,
"'Importance'" as Importance,
"'Level'" as Level,
Date
from  input
pivot(sum(Value) for Scale in ('Importance', 'Level') ) as p
)
group by Elementid, Element
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation`. I am ignoring the date column because you didn't supply it in your sample data. If you need the data aggregated by date as well, add it to the `select` and `group by`. Feel free to change `max` to `sum` if you're looking to sum the values instead of just collapsing

```
select element_id,
       element,
       max(case when scale='Importance' then value end) as importance
       max(case when scale='Level' then value end) as level
from Input Table
group by element_id, element;
```